# Magento 1.7 - Custom module, call function

Tags: php, magento, module, block

I created a custom module where i want to show some information about an product.
In config.xml i added

```
<blocks>
    <mymodule>
        <class>Namespace_MyModule_Block</class>
    </mymodule>
</blocks>
```

The block class extends **Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View**.
But i can't call

```
$this->getProduct()
```

in the *.phtml file according to the module (mymodule.phtml).
The xmls are configured well, so i can call the .phtml with

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mymodule'); ?>
```

but $product is always null. According to the configuration in modules config.xml $this->getProduct() should access Mynamespace_MyModule_Block_View and call the function. I tried with a dummy function which simply returns a string value, but this doesn't work either.

I hope someone can give me a hint weather there is some missing or wrong configuration.

**EDIT 1: Content of layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info">
            <block type="core/template" name="product_available_price" as="product_available_price"
                   template="productavailable/price.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="product_available_info" as="product_available_info"
                   template="productavailable/info.phtml"/>
            <block type="core/template" name="product_available_button" as="product_available_button"
                   template="productavailable/button.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

In button.phtml i call $this->getProduct() and the method is in Mynamespace_MyModule_Block_Button

Comment: Maybe you should add in the question the contents of your layout file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in one of my custom module i have used like below

**class Yournamespace_Brand_Block_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract**

And i have also used all product features with magento default functionality like

pagination and toolbar etc.

**Edit**

Block type change from  `core/template` to `productavailable/button`

```
 <block type="productavailable/button" name="product_available_button" as="product_available_button"                       template="productavailable/button.phtml"/>
```

hope this will sure solve your issue.

let me know if i could help you more.

Comment: I tried `class Mynamespace_ProductAvailable_Block_Button  extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract` but calling $this->getProduct in button.phtml still returns null.

Comment: try to call in your block file and then assign or return to your phtml files

Comment: How do you mean "assign or return"? I tried some similar functionality as in default view.phtml, where $this->getProduct() from View.php gets called.

Comment: make some custom function  and call it in block file

Comment: I'm not able to show anything from block file in template file. I wrote in block file `public function getString(){return "String";}` and called in phtml echo $this->getString(). Still null. I suppose i have some configuration mistake, that template isn't assigned to the block file.

Comment: sorry for misunderstanding you block type should be like this mymodule/block not core template

Comment: @s4lfish, if i could help you, it would be glad if u acpt and vote up my answer

Comment: If i change it in productavailable.xml to `<block type="productavailable/block" name="product_available_button" as="product_available_button"
                   template="productavailable/button.phtml"/>` i can't call the block with $this->getChildHtml('product_available_button').

Comment: i think you dont have any child block in your xml so you can not call it. you can call function which define in button block.

Comment: Ah, i found my mistake. It should be `<block type="productavailable/button"...` due to ProductAvailable_Block_Button.php. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: @s4lfish,glad to help you.

Comment: @s4lfish, it is not to good to change my answer to accept to diaccept.  i already told you to change your block type before other can give you answer. very bad

Comment: Yes you told me in comments, but if i can't accept comments as correct answer. And your initial answer wasn't the solution. If you post the correct answer again as answer, i will sure accept it. Please read my comment to JNDPNT answer.

Comment: yes i was read before adding comment. no worries.cool.sorry for more words.i will sure update my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I didn't understand your problem, but if i'm correct you trying to call `$this->getProduct()` which is a function in your custom Block `Mynamespace_ProductAvailable_Block_Button`. If I look at your xml your block is not linked to the phtml:

```
 <block type="core/template" name="product_available_button" as="product_available_button"
               template="productavailable/button.phtml"/>
```

This should be:

```
 <block type="productavailable/button" name="product_available_button" as="product_available_button"
                   template="productavailable/button.phtml"/>
```

The "type" attribute links the block to the phtml, so you're missing this. Now you are using the core template class which does not have a `getProduct()` method

Comment: This is exactly the answer. Liyakat did also mention this mistake in comments, but for further visitors i accept this answer, so they can quickly find the solution.